# How to pass positional arguments to an interactive bash session

Tags: bash, interactive-shell, positional-parameter

I wanted to start an interactive bash shell like this :

```
bash (...some options) 1 2 3
```

so that in the shell session, I have $1=1, ...

I didn't find any options to achieve the effect.

I tried this, thought it might work :

```
bash -c bash _ 1 2 3
```

but it didn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [bash invoking bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html):

> -s
>
> If this option is present, or if no arguments remain after option processing, then commands are read from the standard input. This
>   option allows the positional parameters to be set when invoking an
>   interactive shell or when reading input through a pipe.

```
$ bash -s 1 2 3
$ echo $1
1 
$ exit
$
```

Comment: One more question, when I do `bash --rcfile customized-bashrc -s 1 2 3`, in customized-bashrc, is there a way to get "$@" ?

Comment: @Philippe — there are two possibilities: yes and no.  Have you tried accessing `$#`, `"$@"`, `$1` etc from inside the customized startup file?  There's a moderate chance they're available.  It would be the work of moments to add `echo "$0: ($#) $*" >&2` near the top of the startup file, and then see whether your message appears and what the values are.  That sort of context is one of the few times when it is sensible to use `$*` instead of `"$@"`.  Of course, you could also write `echo "$0: ($#)" "$@" >&2`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, In customized-bashrc, I just put nothing else but `echo "$@"`, which echo nothing.Only in the shell itself, when I do `echo "$@"`, I get `1 2 3`

Comment: When I put in customized-bashrc, `echo $# - "$@" - $1`, as you suggested, I get `0 - -`

Comment: @Philippe — So that probably means the answer is "No" — the command line arguments are not available inside the customized startup file. Sorry, but short of hacking the Bash source, there isn't a lot you can do about it. You could scrutinize [Invoking Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Invoking-Bash) but I didn't get enlightenment from it that would definitively help you—except … `bash -c 'exec bash -s "$@"' quarantine 1 2 3`—when I run that, the sub-shell has `$0` of `quarantine` and `$3` is 3 and `$@` contains `1`, `2` and `3`. Is that what you're after? _It's devious!_

Comment: I started reading bash sources on this, and [positional parameters are set up](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/shell.c#L672) before [calling startup_file](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/shell.c#L694) and [bashrc](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/shell.c#L1113). But the `$@` is empty in startup file, so I guess it's somewhere else. As a workaround I see do it [like here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123103/how-to-keep-bash-running-after-command-execution) and `source` your rc files and pass args manually.

Comment: To keep it simple for now, I'm using env vars, which are less clean than positional parameters.